# MS-Flow Outcome of "Create an approval"

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, approval, ms-flow

I have created an MS-Flow that requests approval.

One can approve either from the approval email or directly from the web UI that has been designed to approve any requests. UI and approval email updates the same task list in the Sharepoint.

In this scenario, I do not want to "start and wait for approval"(where approver can approve even from the UI) but I want to update the Sharepoint task list once the approver approves either from the mail or the UI, if I use, "create an approval" Action there is no outcome option.

Can someone suggest to me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when you use "create an approval" you need to add "Wait for an approval" action and pass Approval ID to it . the wait for an approval will get you the approval outcome .

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But I don't want the flow to wait till it is approved from the mail because the approver can approve even from the web UI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Even the approver , action from UI or email the workflow will give the outcome only through "Wait for an approval" .